# AngularJS loop through array (series of numbers)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, numbers

I have series of numbers  $scope.N = [1,2,3,4]; I want to ng-repeat this in my Html code, something like JSON ng-repeat example

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in categories">
       <td>{{row.category}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Hov to do that with array of numbers ?

Comment: do u want to show array values in a dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
   <td ng-bind="num"></td>
</tr>
```

You can of course declare the array in your controller:

```
$scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

And then use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="num in numbers">
   <td ng-bind="num"></td>
</tr>
```